# Mapbox control customize button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Currently I'm using drawing functionality of mapbox, but the button of start drawing is like other controls (like gps) are mapbox built in control buttons on the corner of the map.

Is there anyway that I can put the functionality to my cusomized button outside of the map component?

Answer (score 1):

inspect the button and check the class name of them.
then put your map box in a div with {position: relative}, with your desired width and height
then give absolute position to your buttons..